# Is a twisted Edwards curve an elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I don't belong to the Math department. Currently, I am studying Elliptic curves for cryptographic applications. While going through the definition of elliptic curves, it states that

> Elliptic curve is a curve of the form $y^2 = p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is a cubic polynomial with no repeated roots.

But, the twisted Edwards curve which belongs to the Elliptic curve family has an equation $a\ X^2 + Y^2 = 1 + d\ X^2Y^2$, which is not a cubic equation.

Why is this equation considered an elliptic curve equation even though it does not go with the definition of the elliptic curves?

Comment: As on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve): Every Edwards curve is birationally equivalent to an elliptic curve in Weierstrass form.., which means roughly that there is a rational function (ratio of polynomials) that transform Edward's curves to Weierstrass form curves (that is, $y^2 = p(x)$, which $p$ cubic in $x$) and vice versa.

Comment: Elliptic curves are curves of genus one. The Weierstrass model $y^2=\ $ cubic is one way of constructing them, the Edwards formula is another. One needs some algebraic geometry (birational equivalence etc.) to fully understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a twisted Edwards curve:

$$a\ X^2 + Y^2 = 1 + d\ X^2 Y^2$$

Make the substitutions $X=\frac x y$ and $Y = \frac {x-1}{x+1}$

$$
\begin{align}
a\,\left(\frac xy\right)^2 + \left(\frac {x-1}{x+1}\right)^2 
&= 1 + d\,\left(\frac xy\right)^2 \left(\frac {x-1}{x+1}\right)^2
\\
a\, x^2 (x+1)^2 + y^2(x-1)^2
&= y^2 (x+1)^2 + d\, x^2 (x-1)^2
\\
y^2(4x)
&=x^2\left( ax^2 + 2ax + a - dx^2 + 2dx - d \right)
\\
\therefore y^2
&=\frac {a-d} 4 x^3 + \frac {a+d} 2 x^2 + \frac {a-d} 4 x
\\
&= \textrm{a cubic polynomial } p(x)
\end{align}
$$
This is the equivalence to an elliptic curve. ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve#Equivalence_with_twisted_Edwards_curves).)